# Cannot override $.rails.allowAction

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need to customize confirm boxes in my rails application. I found [this](http://rors.org/demos/custom-confirm-in-rails), added the js code into my application.js but it seems that $.rails is undefined.

Here is the code I added to application.js file:

```
$.rails.allowAction = function(link) {
  if (!link.attr('data-confirm')) {
   return true;
  }
  $.rails.showConfirmDialog(link);
  return false;
};

$.rails.confirmed = function(link) {
  link.removeAttr('data-confirm');
  return link.trigger('click.rails');
};

$.rails.showConfirmDialog = function(link) {
  var html, message;
  message = link.attr('data-confirm');
  html = "<div class=\"modal\" id=\"confirmationDialog\">\n  <div class=\"modal-header\">\n    <a class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"modal\">Ã</a>\n    <h3>Are you sure Mr. President?</h3>\n  </div>\n  <div class=\"modal-body\">\n    <p>" + message + "</p>\n  </div>\n  <div class=\"modal-footer\">\n    <a data-dismiss=\"modal\" class=\"btn\">Cancel</a>\n    <a data-dismiss=\"modal\" class=\"btn btn-primary confirm\">OK</a>\n  </div>\n</div>";
  $(html).modal();
  return $('#confirmationDialog .confirm').on('click', function() {
    return $.rails.confirmed(link);
  });
};
```

I got an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'allowAction' of undefined".

Do you know what's wrong? (jquery_ujs gem is installed and loaded successfully)

Thank you in advance,

Jercoh

Answer (score 3):

You need:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

not the jquery_ujs.

Comment: Since you said you put this in application.js you're probably not using asset pipeline, so I'd check the order of loading scripts. This stuff should be at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

I put this code into a file called custom.confirm.js and then put those two lines

```
//= require jquery_ujs 
//= require custom.confirm.js
```

at the bottom of application.js, and it worked, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, it worked fine on Firefox but not Chrome. I guess it was due to Chrome cache and fixed it by cleaning all browser cache related with my development server,